# How do I work with MSBuild using the interactive switch

Tags: msbuild, interactive

I am working on creating a custom .targets file for MSBuild Based compilation for my custom visual studio project.

I have been able to create a targets file which does the work of Build / Rebuild and Clean correctly.

However, I have a scenario where I need to provide some additional input during MSBuild Compilation. In the [MSBuild command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022#switches), there are sections which talk about running MSBuild Interactively and with Response Files (.rsp).

Checking in the community here if someone has worked with making msbuild interactive or providing response through .rsp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For normal builds you shouldn't have to deal with `interactive`, it's used only for things like NuGet: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/3697.

Response files are text files with msbuild arguments which can be used instead of specifying them on the commandline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-response-files

So a my.rsp file containing

```
# Comment in an response file.
/p:x=y
/t:mytarget
```

and using `msbuild foo.proj @my.rsp` is equivalent to `msbuild foo.proj /p:x=y /t:mytarget`

Comment: I have a scenario, where I may need to take additional inputs from the user. The compiler for which I am writing the MSBuild Target generates interrupts whenever it needs any additional information and waits for input. It does not accept that information in advance. I understand that in normal builds the `interactive` is not required, and that is why my MSBuild targets accepts an additional MSBuild property which will be provided to the compiler whenever required. However, I wanted to explore the functionality of interactive and see if it can be used in my case.

Comment: So, is the `interactive` only for NuGet? or it can be used in my case also.

Comment: It's not *only* for NuGet, but that is one of the few things it is currently used for. So sure, if you want to use it you could. However in that case, if the user would pass -interactive:false, you'd also have to adhere to that and make sure your builds eaffectively run without any interaction. Note that passing /interactive doesn't 'do' anything, it just sets a builtin property.

Comment: Is there any documentation available on how can I take inputs during MSBuild.

Comment: That's a bit out of scope for msbuild itself; you could show a dialog or get input from the prompt. A search for 'msbuild ask user input' shows e.g. MSBuild.Community.Tasks having a target for prompting, and MSBuild.Extension.Pack for showing a dialog.